# validation is not allowed - hapi js

Tags: node.js, validation, hapi.js

I have listen alot about hapi api framework, so i started with it. Although documentation is very solid but still i am not able to solve my issue:

I am trying to send some form data and want that to be validated before actual processing, so i am using hapi's powerful validation utility and getting following error:

```
←[31m
[1] validation is not allowed←[0m
    at Object.exports.assert (E:\repository\simpleHapiApp\node_modules\hapi\node
_modules\hoek\lib\index.js:425:11)
    at Object.exports.assert (E:\repository\simpleHapiApp\node_modules\hapi\lib\
schema.js:15:10)
    at new module.exports.internals.Route (E:\repository\simpleHapiApp\node_modu
les\hapi\lib\route.js:46:12)
    at E:\repository\simpleHapiApp\node_modules\hapi\lib\router.js:110:25
    at Array.forEach (native)
    at E:\repository\simpleHapiApp\node_modules\hapi\lib\router.js:107:17
    at Array.forEach (native)
    at internals.Router.add (E:\repository\simpleHapiApp\node_modules\hapi\lib\r
outer.js:104:13)
    at internals.Server._route (E:\repository\simpleHapiApp\node_modules\hapi\li
b\server.js:471:18)
    at internals.Server.route (E:\repository\simpleHapiApp\node_modules\hapi\lib
\server.js:465:10)
```

my code looks like following:

```
server.route({
    method: 'POST',
    path: '/apis/login',
    handler: empApi.login,
    config:{
        validation:{
            payload: {
                username: joi.string().min(3).max(20).required(),
                password: joi.string().alphanum().required()
            }
        }
    }
});
```

Please point out where is the mistake.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

After an hour of debugging, and just after reviewing my own question, I found how silly is the mistake I made: the key is not `validation`, but it is `validate`.

So, once corrected, the code looks like this:

```
server.route({
    method: 'POST',
    path: '/apis/login',
    handler: empApi.login,
    config:{
        validate:{
            headers: {
                username: joi.string().min(3).max(20).required(),
                password: joi.string().alphanum().required()
            }
        }
    }
});
```